# Cabal build error

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

Ciao folks!

I followed the instruction to build the EnglishAuction.hs contract but I am getting the following when run the `cabal build` command.

```
Warning: Requested index-state 2021-10-20T00:00:00Z is newer than
'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2021-10-19T23:39:06Z).
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: Win32-network-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: base-4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0 (dependency of Win32-network)
[__2] trying: lobemo-scribe-systemd-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__3] next goal: libsystemd-journal (dependency of lobemo-scribe-systemd)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.5 (conflict: pkg-config package
libsystemd>=209, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.4 (conflict:
base==4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0, libsystemd-journal => base>=4.6 && <4.13)
[__3] skipping: libsystemd-journal-1.4.3, libsystemd-journal-1.4.2,
libsystemd-journal-1.4.1, libsystemd-journal-1.4.0, libsystemd-journal-1.3.4,
libsystemd-journal-1.3.3, libsystemd-journal-1.3.1, libsystemd-journal-1.3.0,
libsystemd-journal-1.2.0, libsystemd-journal-1.1.0, libsystemd-journal-1.0.0
(has the same characteristics that caused the previous version to fail:
excludes 'base' version 4.14.1.0)
[__3] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd, Win32-network
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

I am running it from the `nix-shell` after a successful `cabal update`

Can you help me?

Comment: I remember receiving the same error while being in the wrong commit. Did you do `git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a` inside plutus-apps before `nix-shell`?

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` will show your current commit

Comment: Dumb me! was executing the commands outside the nix-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Could not resolve dependencies` error is due to not running the command in the nix-shell.